# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useSelector.attendance')

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Any idea why I am getting the error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_useSelector.attendance') with redux.. Everything seems to be working fine but I just done understand why it keeps coming back to this.

Reducers.js

```
import { GET_ATTENDANCE, ADD_TO_ATTENDANCE_LIST } from "./actions";


const initialState = () => ({
  attendance: [],
  attendancebook: [],
});

function attendanceReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ATTENDANCE:
      return { ...state, attendance: action.payload };
    case ADD_TO_ATTENDANCE_LIST:
      return {
        ...state,
        attendancebook: [...state.attendancebook, action.payload],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default attendanceReducer;
```

AttendanceScreen.js

```
function AttendanceScreen({ route }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const listing = route.params;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { attendance, attendancebook } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.attendanceReducer
  );

  const getAttendance = () => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ATTENDANCE,
        payload: attendancelist,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const fetchAttendance = () => dispatch(getAttendance());

  const addToAttendanceList = (data) => dispatch(addAttendance(data));

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAttendance();
  }, []);
```

store.js

```
import attendanceReducer from "./reducers";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ["attendancebook"],
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  attendanceReducer: persistReducer(persistConfig, attendanceReducer),
});

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

actions.js

```
export const GET_ATTENDANCE = "GET_ATTENDANCE";
export const ADD_TO_ATTENDANCE_LIST = "ADD_TO_ATTENDANCE_LIST";

export const addAttendance = (data) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: ADD_TO_ATTENDANCE_LIST,
    payload: data,
  });
};
```

Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do your store setup and root reducer definition look like?

Comment: I just updated it. Thank you for setting out time to help @markerikson

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone, I spent an hour on this...

I kept getting this error after adding a new reducer to our project. Don't just hot reload.  Instead of hitting restart app when the error screen comes up on your device, completely close the app by swiping it out and restarting.  Even though i set initial state in the reducer, i wasn't propagating by hitting restart on the error screen.  The app needs to fully reboot.